# how to find out android:requiresSmallestWidthDp for support-screens

Tags: android

How do I figure what value to set the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp under

I would like to support small screens, but I can see that at 3.3 in things start to get cut off.

I don't specify any sizes in the layout. Mainly use relative layout, and wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest ) this parameter is currently ignored not only by the Android device, but, currently, by Google Play as well.  So it does absolutely nothing currently.  Unless your app development is being done under unusual circumstances, including this in your app at the moment would be "gold plating" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_%28software_engineering%29 ).  In other words, you probably should not put this in your manifest at this time.

Presumably, at some point in the future, Google Play will filter based on this parameter.  At that point it will become useful and people will begin including the parameter in their manifests.

Comment: In that case, how do I test for the smallest screen device in the emulator? I have read that I have to use QVGA, and this has a 320x240 screen resolution with 120 dpi. However, when I set it up in the emulator and asks for actual screen device in the launch options, this ends up being 3.3 in, but I believe the smallest screen device is 2.5 in. I am not sure if my calculation of screen size based on the resolution and dpi is correct.